# Hide the toolbar which shows class functions

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to hide this toolbar?

[image: toolbar]

Also, how can I disable the popup window which say "Typo: In world.."? I hate this because it shows in comments and in words which are in brackets.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Toolbar can be disabled here:

[image: toolbar]

Typo inspection can be disabled or configured to ignore comments:

[image]